# Line height is not working in mobile for my portfolio site

Tags: css, mobile

New to stack overflow, but I was struggling on this one. I recently created my portfolio site which appears to be working across all device break points and the media query on my laptop in Chrome. However, when I go to the site on my phone (tried both Chrome and Firefox) the header line-height disappears. It's crunched and unreadable. Any ideas what might be happening there? I'd really appreciate it! It seems impossible to debug because it's only happening via mobile.

```css
.text--header {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 38px;
  display: block;
  font-stretch: none;
  margin-top: 95px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 630px) {
  .text--header {
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: -0.04em;
    line-height: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ct ct--body">
  <span class="text text--header">Jenna is a Product/Visual Designer.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: plz show your code

Comment: The entire HTML/CSS code or...?

Comment: not really
just the code that is giving trouble (related HTML and CSS)

Comment: `<div class="ct ct--body">
      <span class="text text--header">Jenna is a Product/Visual Designer.</span>
      
    </div>`


`.text--header {
font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 38px;
    display: block;
    font-stretch: none;
    margin-top: 95px;
}`

<br/>
`@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 630px)
.text--header {
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: -0.04em;
    line-height: 32px;

  }`

Hopefully this helps. It appears normally in the browser at each breakpoint on my laptop.

Comment: @jenna alway post relevant information in the question via an edit so that the full story is all in one place.   Please delete your latest comment and add it to your question.

Comment: at my end, I see everything is working fine.
Could you please share snapshot of your problem?

Comment: [Link to what is happening on mobile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxb5pvgsypfnpas/Photo%20Nov%2001%2C%2011%2029%2056%20PM.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem in Media query won't forget to follow standard declarations of the media query.

```css
.text--header { 
font-size: 30px; 
line-height: 38px; 
display: block; 
font-stretch: none; 
margin-top: 95px; 
background-color: #ccc; 
}  
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 630px) {
.text--header { 
 font-size: 30px; 
 letter-spacing: -0.04em; 
 line-height: 32px; 
 background-color: red;
 }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<body>
 <div class="ct ct--body"> 
  <span class="text text--header">Jenna is a Product/Visual Designer.</span> 
  </div>
</body>
```

Appreciate if it is useful :)